# Impact of SQL injection on SELECT statement

Tags: sql-injection, sql-server, risk-classification

During a routine penetration test I encountered a possibility for SQL injection. The following criteria apply:

- Microsoft SQL Server (2016);
- Query has to start with `SELECT`;
- The semicolon `;` is not allowed to break a statement and to start a new one;
- Everything else is allowed.

I am wondering what the highest possible impact would be for an SQL injection vulnerability like this one. Obviously information disclosure is possible, but I would like to know if it is also possible to actually 'break out' of the `SELECT` statement and to `DROP` a table for example. What would you suggest for this scenario?

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, but if you can do something like EXEC (@sqlCommand) in the select command, everything else is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain on this first detail so I'll defer to anyone who disagrees, but I'm pretty sure that your stipulations mean that it is *not* possible to break out and execute a `DROP`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or anything other than a simple select.

As a result the worst case scenario is limited to information disclosure, but keep in mind that the worst case scenario is most likely a complete leak of your **entire** database.  With MySQL at least (I'm not familiar with the details of Microsoft SQL Server) the table structure is also stored as tables that can be accessible via a `SELECT` operation and so `SQLi` vulnerabilities on a `SELECT` usually start by first figuring out all column and table names (presuming that you can perform arbitrary `SELECT` injections - which is what it sounds like).  Once you have that it is very easy to join and dump all tables and columns, resulting in a complete copy of your entire database (as well as any other databases that the SQL user has access to).

A quick google leads me to believe that database structure is accessible via SQL select commands in Microsoft SQL just like it is in MySQL - ergo a full database copy is possible in the event of a wide open select vulnerability.